# How to tap a pin on very small surface mounted IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, pins

I have very small surface mounted IC (see link https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l486qg.pdf).

I need to access some pins on the IC in order to perform ETM trace.  My challenge so far has been how to tap into the pin.

Would I need any specialized tool?

Comment: There are test clips that get quite small but they can be very expensive. The X2015 is the smallest one I know of but still too big I think. https://e-z-hook.com/test-hooks/micro-hook/

If you are making the PCB yourself you should just run a test point to each pin so you can clip onto it with a regular clip.

Comment: Oh, do you actually have the QG package? That's a BGA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test hook may not be suitable for high speed operation such as ETM trace.

If your package is QFP then you can take FRC cable and solder it to required pin. Soldering is not an issue for 0.5 mm pitch chip, use flux along with solder wire to ease your job.

You can also use glue to fix FRC wire on board so that the pin won't get damaged during handling.

[image: FRC Cable]